# Django - Fetched foreign key is shown as dropdown in upload page. How to show the last entered data?

Tags: django, file-upload, foreign-keys

I have a main form and an upload form where i use foreign key to get the id from the main form. In my upload page, the ID's are shown as a dropdown. Is there a way to show only the latest ID instead of the dropdown

I am not sure if my understanding is right but think there is something to change in the main model return str.

This is the main form

```py
class MDform(models.Model):


    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

This is my upload model

```py
class uploadmeta(models.Model):

    path = models.ForeignKey(MDform, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="aaData/")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('file_list')
```

I am not able to attach a screenshot of my output. its a dropdown with all the id from the main form and the upload file option

Answer (score 1):

sDo this changes in your forms.py:

```
 class uploadmetaform(forms.ModelForm):
        len_mdform = MDform.objects.all().latest('id').id#To know the id of latest object
        data = MDform.objects.all().filter(id=len_mdform) #return the queryset with only latest object
        path = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(uploadmetaform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            len_mdform = MDform.objects.all().latest('id').id
            data = MDform.objects.all().filter(id=len_mdform)
            self.fields['path'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data)

        class Meta:
              model = uploadmeta
              fields = ['path','tar_gif']
```

The **forms.ModelChoiceField** takes only a queryset in its queryset argument,we cannot send a single instance in it,that's why i first find the id of MDform latest instance then using that id we will get the latest instance in queryset.
Now only the id of latest forign key will be displayed in the dropdown.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: really appreciate your time to answer. i made the changes to the form, now the path does not list any id. It is just a blank dropdown

Comment: The id field in your model starts from 0 or 1?

Comment: You have made custom id field,does it starts from 0?

Comment: its an autofield, i am sorry i dont know what you mean by 0 or 1

Comment: It should have shown the latest data,is there any data present in MDform model?

Comment: I edited my answer,  use MDform.objects.all().latest('id') in place of MDform.objects.all().count()

Comment: I am getting a new error now: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'MDform'

Comment: MDform.objects.all().latest('id').id

Comment: Add .id after latest

Comment: Great...Thanks a ton. But i see that after i submit the form and go to the upload page, the latest Id is not shown, the id before this form submission is shown but after i again run manage.py it shows the latest id. can this be sorted to?

Comment: You are submitting the form for updatemeta,right? so in this case,the MDform model will have no effect,means a new MDform object is not created,that's why the same id is displayed.

Comment: I am submitting the MDform that has the id as primary key. I am using this id as foreign key in the uploadmeta page.. which is the upload page. So when i submit the MDform a new id i created in the database. I want to upload a file to the same id. That is why i got the id as foreign key. Now if i upload data for the last but one id then the files will not be linked.

Comment: We are now at a good position,and this form not updating is a new issue,i will  see what can be done for this.

Comment: I edited my answer,now foreignkey id will get updated if the page is refreshed

Comment: You are really a good programmer, thank you for the guidance. It works perfectly fine now.

Comment: i need another help with the same kind but now with the username being fetched from the userprofile as foreignkey and want to show only the logged in user not the list of all users in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can use .latest() function here.
In order to get the latest id from MDform,write this in your views.py

```
mdform = MDform.objects.all().latest('id') #It will return the latest MDform object
latest_md_form = mdform.id #In order to get the id of latest mdform object
```

You can then send latest_md_form or mdform as context in your response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If i am creating another view i can do that, how do i do it when i do an upload. This is my upload view: def uploaddata(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = uploadmetaform(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        
                        return redirect('file_list')
        else:
                form = uploadmetaform()
        return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {
                'form': form
        })

Comment: this is my form: 
class uploadmetaform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = uploadmeta
        fields = ['path','tar_gif',]